# Closing old php websocket

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am using [PHP-Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets) to create a simple chat server. I have everything working correctly when I run the php script that creates the websocket on my server for the first time. If the script stops for some reason and I try to rerun it, I get an error saying that the script could not bind the socket because it already exists.

How can I make a script to find this old socket (given that I know which port it is running on) and close it so I can make a new connection?

Comment: You can use the `disconnect` method in that class to disconnect if already connected

Comment: What disconnect method are you referring to? I can't find it on this php functions page - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

Comment: You need to figure out how to enable `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: It's there in `websockets.php` that you are using https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets/blob/master/websockets.php

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am currently using this option and it still isn't working - socket_set_option($this->master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

Comment: @Dr.Dan I can't use that function because I don't know how to get the original socket to pass into the function. Otherwise I could also use it to pass into the socket_close() function.

Answer (score 2):

If you have shell access, I would use the following command to deduce the PID of the process using that socket (port).

```
netstat --tcp --listening --program
```

Then kill that process.

```
kill %pid%
```

To prevent this from happening though, I would double check that your script terminates gracefully and closes the socket first.

Comment: Thanks Jon, this will work but I am trying to figure out a way for my server to handle this function without me logging in to do it manually. As for the script ending properly, it does. I am trying to implement this as a worst case senario so my chat functionality is always running.

Comment: @anonymousfox: When you do that manually, what process do you wind up killing?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Actually I spoke too quickly. I thought that what Jon said would work but when I try it, no process is listed that is connected to the socket. And when I kill/restart apache, it does nothing to the websocket. The only thing I can do is restart the server altogether.

Comment: It doesn't clear after two minutes or so? If no process owns the port and it doesn't clear after a few minutes, you have a kernel or driver bug on your hands.

Comment: Not necessarily a driver bug - plz check the timeouts of your network-connection. I had a similar problem in java with tcp-sockets and completely different behaviour on different computers. In the end it were different timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Ubuntu(linux) server:

Here is how I solved it:
using `exec()` function you can easily terminate running web socket:
let a php file named `socketControl.php` and the code:

```
exec('kill $(pidof php)');
```

this should cancel currently running php websocket in server.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
port=12345
echo "Kill all Processes of ${port}"
kill $(lsof -t -i:${port})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it