# PHP websockets socket.bind() failed. Closing old php websocket

Tags: php, websocket, drupal-7

I am facing  the same issue related to the thread [Closing old php websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931101/closing-old-php-websocket)

> am using Websockets to create a simple chat server. I have
>   everything working correctly when I run the php script that creates
>   the websocket on my server for the first time. If the script stops for
>   some reason and I try to rerun it, I get an error saying that the
>   script could not bind the socket because it already exists.

How can I make a script to find this old socket (given that I know which port it is running on) and close it so I can make a new connection?

In my local server I used to  fetch and kill the process.

```
netstat -lntu
```

Then kill that process.

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:9064) ,9064 is the port.
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I like storing my pid to a file on socket startup.

```
if (!file_put_contents(self::WEBSOCKET_ACTIVE_PID, getmypid())) {
    print 'Failed to store PID to file.';
    exit(1);
}
```

Then the following could be run in a shell.

```
kill -15 `cat websocket_pid.txt` || rm websocket_pid.txt || echo 'It does not look like a socket is running on this subdomain.'
```

Note you might consider more robust cases where you would rely on a [php signal handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php).